# Conditional on counter definition (TeX)

Tags: conditionals, counters

Is there a way to make a conditional where the test is the definition of a counter with a specific name, i.e. "if there exists a counter named foo, then do [bar], otherwise do [baz]"? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: `\@ifundefined{c@foo}{No foo counter}{There's a foo counter}`

Comment: `\@ifundefined{c@mycounter}{something}{something else}`

Comment: @egreg can type faster than me